# Convolutional Neural Network to detect watermark images

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have two different sets of images , one we have water mark that we want to keep and other set of images we have water mark but we dont want to keep that

how can i train i model to detect the watermark images that i want to keep and to detect the images that i dont want to keep since all images has water mark

Regards
Prince Bhatia

Comment: Sounds like straight-forward supervised classification. Start by trying transfer learning on a pre-trained CNN.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? The title says that you want to detect images with water marks, but the question seems to imply that you have two categories of images which you want to binarily classify.

Comment: Yes i have two categories of images, one with watermark that i want to keep and others are also with watermark but i dont want to keep, how can i train my model to detect images that i want to keep and also that i dont want to keep since all the images have watermark.

Apologies for title ,  i am not so good in english and nothing came in mind so wrote that title. I will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical classification problem. There are many frameworks like TensorFlow, Keras, Caffe which support this out of the box.

All you've to do is to create the required directory structures with images.

The link below explains about building an image classifier using keras.

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html